# Hadoop via Hive using C#

Tags: c#, hadoop

I am doing sample POC of 'Communicate to Hadoop via Hive using .NET/C#'

For this I am refering this article - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/738141/How-to-communicate-to-Hadoop-via-Hive-using-NET-Cs

I found Microsoft Hive ODBC driver here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/hdinsight-connect-excel-hive-odbc-driver/

Connection String mentioned in this article looks like this -

```
ConnectionString = @"DRIVER={Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver};                                        
                                        Host=server_name;
                                        Port=10000;
                                        Schema=default;
                                        DefaultTable=table_name;
                                        HiveServerType=1;
                                        ApplySSPWithQueries=1;
                                        AsyncExecPollInterval=100;
                                        AuthMech=0;
                                        CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=0;
                                        TrustedCerts=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver\lib\cacerts.pem;"
```

Since we do not have any big data source. I can not use above connection string for my POC.

So my questions are-

1. Is there any public data source available for free or trial purpose?
2. How do I connect to public data source using Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver?

Thanks.

Comment: You can download a virtual machine from one of the Hadoop vendors (e.g. Cloudera QuickStart VM) and run a sandbox cluster on your computer.